# Https issue with subdomain pointing to Azure VM

Tags: azure, ssl, https, dns, virtual-machine

I have a domain purchased from Godaddy. Then a Virtual Machine setup on Azure with an web application installed on it.

So thus far I have:

1. An Azure VM with an application running on it, lets say the ip for the VM is **12.3.456.789**
2. A domain name I purchased from godaddy, e.g **mydomain.com**, I then created a subdomain for e.g **sub.mydomain.com**
3. I then added an SSL certificate to this subdomain which worked fine, after I changed the DNS A record for the subdomain to the ip address of the VM **12.3.456.789**, also the application on the VM is accessed on port 4000. So **https://sub.mydomain.com:4000**

The issue is that when I access my domain via https I get the ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR in all browsers but when I access it via http then the application on it loads completely fine.

Any ideas on what I would have **done wrong** or left out in my setup?

Also if I did not provide enough information do let me know.

Comment: I think you just need to configure the SSL in your application server (IIS, tomcat, etc). Another possible issue, your certificate is not a wildcard type, which won't work for subdomains

Comment: @ThiagoCustodio Thanks for the response, the certificate was one purchased for the subdomain specifically and prior to changing the A record for the subdomain the website  loaded over https. Could I be missing something?

Answer (score 0):

commercial SSL certs are always signed to include the **TLD**

(Top Level Domain -> in your hypothetical case: mydomain.com) !

You should contact godaddy to change the certificate to change the SAN  (Subject alternative Name to **sub.mydomain.com**)

One example:
You order a ssl certificate for the subdomain www for your domain mydomain.com.

mydomain.com is valid by its nature (SAN -> it's the TLD)
Whereas **[www.mydomain.com](http://www.mydomain.com)** is the **SUBJECT**.

Best H.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I got my certificate from zerossl. But the certificate on my main domain is a different certificate from the one on my main domain

Answer (score 0):

To rewrite to rule from https as you are getting ERR_SSL_PROTOCOL_ERROR please check you are correctly provided ssl cerficate [SSL Certificate Checker](https://www.digicert.com/help/)  as my SSL provided is DigiCert.

And to make Https ensure in your remote desktop in IIS manager ***click your virtual machine ->binding -> Https and port as 443 and upload certificate.***

[image]

In your virtual machine try to add outbound security rule provide service as HTTPS and port as same in 443

[image]

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/23397/not-able-to-secure-windows-azure-vm-in-https.html

Comment: Thanks for the info, I've added the outbound rule but still no luck.

My SSL is from zerossl and prior to changing the A record for the subdomain I checked the SSL and it was valid

Comment: Please check this which gives to info https://youtu.be/pPxJoAeySTc

Comment: Ok ill check it out